# Custom Bash prompt is overwriting itself

Tags: bash, command-prompt, gentoo

I'm using custom bash prompt to show git branch.

Everything is in `/etc/bash/bashrc`:

```
function formattedGitBranch {
    _branch="$(git branch 2>/dev/null | sed -e "/^\s/d" -e "s/^\*\s//")"
    # tried these:
    echo -e "\e[0;91m ($_branch)"                       
    echo -e "\e[0;91m ($_branch) \e[m"                  
    echo -e $'\e[0;91m'"($_branch)"
    echo "($_branch)"                                   
    echo "$(tput setaf 2) ($_branch) $(tput setaf 9)"
    printf "\e[0;91m ($_branch)"
}

# color is set before function call
PS1='\[\033[01;34m\] \[\033[0;91m\]$(formattedGitBranch) \$\[\033[00m\] '
# color is set inside function
PS1='\[\033[01;34m\] $(formattedGitBranch) \$\[\033[00m\] '
```

Problem is that when I set color for `$_branch` in the function, my prompt will be overwritten when EOL is reached:

[image: mmmmmmmmmmmmp/rainyday.js (master) $ mmmmmmmm]

Tried all possible variants `tput`, `printf`, `$''` notation.

I solved the problem by setting the colour only in `PS1`:

[image: ad@gentoo /tmp/rainyday.js (master) $ mmmmmmm]

But..

1. I would like to know why it is overwriting my prompt
2. How to fix this issue when function is used

I'm using Gentoo Linux. `GNU bash, verze 4.2.37(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)`

Answer (score 67, accepted):

### 1) I would like to know why it is overwriting my prompt

Because every non-printable characters have to be escaped by `\[` and `\]` otherwise [readline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline) cannot keep track of the cursor position correctly.

> You must put `\[` and `\]` around any non-printing escape sequences in your prompt.
>   Without the `\[ \]` bash will think the bytes which constitute the escape sequences for the color codes will actually take up space on the screen, so bash won't be able to know where the cursor actually is.
>
> `\[`   Begin a sequence of non-printing characters. (like color escape sequences). This
>        allows bash to calculate word wrapping correctly.
>
> `\]`   End a sequence of non-printing characters.
>   -- [BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/053)
>
> ...note the escapes for the non printing characters, these ensure that readline can keep track of the cursor position correctly.  -- [ss64.com](http://ss64.com/bash/syntax-prompt.html)

### 2) How to fix this issue when `function` is used

If you want to set colours inside a `function` whose output is used in `PS` you have two options.

- Either escape the whole function call:

  `PS1='\[ $(formattedGitBranch) \] '`
- Or [replace the non-printing Escape](https://superuser.com/a/301355/140711) sequences inside `echo`.  That is, replace:

  `\[` and `\]` with `\001` `\002`

  (thanks to [user grawity](https://superuser.com/users/1686/grawity)!)
- `echo -e` [is not aware](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4T0VQ.png) of bash's `\[`  `\]` so you have to substitute these with `\001` & `\002` ASCII control codes to delimit non-printable chars from printable:

  `function formattedGitBranch { echo -e "\001\e[0;91m\002 ($_branch)"; }`
    `PS1='$(formattedGitBranch) '`

Comment: I was using `\[` without using `\]` and it was causing a similar issue to OP. Thank you.

Comment: If it's not already obvious: in addition to ensuring that all non-printable characters are wrapped in `\[` `\]`, you also have to ensure that all *printable* characters *are not* wrapped. Incorrectly wrapping a printable character causes the same type of problems as failing to wrap a non-printable one.

Comment: I wasn't using `echo -e` for my prompt-string, but I had the same issue. Using `\001` and `\002` instead of `\[` and `\]` also solved it. Many thanks!! It was bugging me for over a year, now.

Comment: The [link](https://superuser.com/a/301355/140711) also suggests to **use the hexadecimal versions** `\x01` and `\x02` instead to avoid a "bash bug that causes it to eat one digit too many when processing octal escapes".

Answer (score 16):

Strings like `\e[0;91m` needs additional quoting, to prevent bash from calculating its length.

Enclose these strings from `formattedGitBranch` in `\[` & `\]` as, `\[\e[0;91m\]`

You have done it correctly in other places. Just missed it in formattedGitBranch.

Comment: No I omitted it becase I have a note in my bashrc that it doesn't work. (My) `echo -e` can't handle `\[  \]`
http://i.stack.imgur.com/4T0VQ.png

But you are probably right that the closing is needed, but I don't have clue how to close it in `echo`.

Comment: `echo` is just producing the characters for the value of `PS1`. The bash shell will handle the actual display of your prompt after removing the `\[` and `\]`.

Comment: @anishsane did you mean: `\[ $(formattedGitBranch) \]`? I was very confused by your last sentence _"Just missed it __in__ formattedGitBranch."_ Thought you are talking about `echo -e ...` which is INside formattedGitBranch function.

Comment: ^^ I have not really tried `echo -e` in PS1, but I suspected that it was the only missing thing. `\[$(formattedGitBranch)\]` is worth trying too.

Comment: downvoter, please let me know what was the mistake, so that I can rectify and learn...

Comment: This was exactly what caused my spacing issue! Replaced `\e[1;32m` by `\[\e[1;32m\]` _etc._ and the prompt was not overwritten / jumped sooner than expected!

Answer (score 0):

You have to take care of non printable character inside [\ and ] otherwise you might be getting cursor right on top of command prompt as shared in question itself , so I found something and just sharing it :-

**For getting cursor after PS1 output on the same line :**

[image: After]

few examples :

```
PS1='[\u@\h:\w]\$
PS1='[\[\033[0;32m\]\u@\h:\[\033[36m\]\W\[\033[0m\]]\$ '
```

Refer Link : [syntax for bash PS1](https://ss64.com/bash/syntax-prompt.html)