# Docker Exec -it bash Terminal Output Improperly Formatted

Tags: docker, iterm2

The command promp after running `docker exec -it ... bash` is not formatted nicely. The problem happens on the OSX terminal or iTerm2. Any setting for the iTerm2 I need to change or is that related to the bash command? Thanks.

Picture:[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think I can tell from the picture that you're not actually talking about `docker logs` (which is a docker real docker command that you *didn't* run). It looks like you want to know why your console output is not printing with nice formatting after you get to a command prompt inside a container with `docker exec -it ... bash`.

I suspect your PS1 length is being calculated incorrectly either inside the container or on your host machine. Read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19092488/custom-bash-prompt-is-overwriting-itself). The prompt inside the container looks like the standard prompt and the prompt on your host machine looks fancy, so I bet you have a problem with the PS1 on your OS X host.

To see if your host machine is causing the problem, drop into a subshell with a minimal PS1, then run Docker and see if the problem persists:

```
$ bash --rcfile <(echo "PS1='$ '") -i
$ docker exec -it ... bash
# ls
```

If the problem goes away, it is a problem with the PS1 on your host machine. Fix it permanently by following the directions in the link above so the length is calculated correctly.

Comment: Many thanks for your comment and I tried your code but still cannot show the message with a correct format. As I have installed the "oh-my-zsh" for the terminal. Is the related to the "oh-my-zsh" setting?Or anything setting I can change to test?

Comment: Seems I reinstall the docker then back to normal. Thanks.

Comment: What the OP is reporting is an issue with TTY initialization on some versions of Docker (now fixed upstream); nothing at all to do with the value of PS1. We have several preexisting questions about this on SO (flagged duplicate of each other) already.